# could not find driver (SQL: select * from `pages` where `default` = 1 limit 1)

Tags: mysql, laravel, debian, mysqli, pdo

работаю с удалённым сервером на debian 10 и при запуске сервера получаю ошибку - [image: ошибка could not find driver (SQL: select * from pages where default = 1 limit 1)]

Перечитал кучу всего, но так и не нашёл решения устанавливал php-mysql, php7.2-mysql, php7.2-pdo (и много другого), но ошибка так и не ушла :\ Поговаривают в других ответах что нет зависимости..., но какой зависимости я вообще беспонятия -_- Кстати да, работаю с laravel

Comment: Ошибка говорит что у вас нет драйвера, посмотрите конфиг, и что в окружении

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена и заключалась как раз в отсутствии mysql драйвера попробуйте
apt install
apt install php7.вашаВерсия-mysql или apt install php7.вашаВерсия-mysqli
Решил давненько поэтому не помню точно какая именно установка мне помогла